# SSRS Report Rendering Error: number of children on page and saved number of children for the page

Tags: reporting-services

I came across this weird issue recently while creating a report. The report would generate fine at first then as I clicked through the pages in the non-print layout the report would fail seemingly randomly around the 5th or 6th page. The error generated was, reportrendering:mismatch between the number of children on page and the saved number of children for the page. The report would not fail while clicking through the print layout but I could see the data not being included in the report past the point the report would fail in the other layout. Is this a common error in SSRS? I could not find any references to it while I was searching for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with my report was in the tablix properties. I was using rectangles to group my tablix's into sections. It seems that since I had set page breaks after some of my tablix's that were contained within the rectangles it was causing this error. Once I fixed the tablix properties to not have page breaks and only applied page breaks after the rectangles the problem was gone. Just posting this in case anyone else encounters that error message as well. I did not see any other help listed for it.